# How to map functions in dask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I'm using Dask to manipulate a dataframe (coming from CSV file) and I'm looking for a way to improve this code using something like `map`, or `apply` functions since in large files is taking so long (I know having nested `for` and using `iterrows()` is the worst think I can make)

```
NAN_VALUES = [-999, "INVALID", -9999]
_all_rows=list()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    _row = list()
    for key, value in row.iteritems():
        if value in NAN_VALUES or pd.isnull(value):
            _row.append(None)
        else:
            _row.append(apply_transform(key, value))
    _all_rows.append(_row)
    rows_count += 1
```

How can I map this code using `map_partitions` or `pandas.map` ?!

EXTRA: a bit more of context:
In order to be able to apply some functions I'm replacing NaN values with a default value. Finally I need to make a list for each row replacing the default values to None.

1.- Original DF

```
 "name"    "age"    "money"
---------------------------
"David"     NaN      12.345 
"Jhon"      22        NaN    
"Charles"   30       123.45 
  NaN       NaN       NaN
```

2.- Passing NaN to Default value

```
 "name"       "age"    "money"
------------------------------
"David"       -999     12.345 
"Jhon"         22      -9999  
"Charles"      30      123.45 
"INVALID"     -999     -9999
```

3.- Parse to a list each row

```
"name"  , "age", "money"
------------------------
["David", None, 12.345]
["Jhon", 22, None]
["Charles", 30, 123.45]
[None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion here is try to work with pandas and then try to translate into dask

## `pandas`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nan = np.nan

df = {'name': {0: 'David', 1: 'John', 2: 'Charles', 3: nan},
 'age': {0: nan, 1: 22.0, 2: 30.0, 3: nan},
 'money': {0: 12.345, 1: nan, 2: 123.45, 3: nan}}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

# These are your default values
diz = {"age": -999, "name": "INVALID", "money": -9999}
```

### Passing NaN to Default value

```py
for k,v in diz.items():
    df[k] = df[k].fillna(v)
```

### Get a list for every row

```py
df.apply(list, axis=1)
```

```
0       [David, nan, 12.345]
1          [John, 22.0, nan]
2    [Charles, 30.0, 123.45]
3            [nan, nan, nan]
dtype: object
```

## `dask`

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

nan = np.nan

df = {'name': {0: 'David', 1: 'John', 2: 'Charles', 3: nan},
 'age': {0: nan, 1: 22.0, 2: 30.0, 3: nan},
 'money': {0: 12.345, 1: nan, 2: 123.45, 3: nan}}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

# These are your default values
diz = {"age": -999, "name": "INVALID", "money": -9999}

# transform to dask dataframe
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
```

### Passing NaN to Default value

This is exactly the same as before. Note that as `dask` is lazy you should run if you want to see the effects `df.compute()`

```py
for k,v in diz.items():
    df[k] = df[k].fillna(v)
```

### Get a list for every row

Here things change a bit as you are asked to state explicitly the dtype of your output

```py
df.apply(list, axis=1, meta=(None, 'object'))
```

In dask you can eventually use `map_partitions` as following

```py
df.map_partitions(lambda x: x.apply(list, axis=1))
```

**Remark** please consider that if your data fits in memory you don't need `dask` and `pandas` could be faster.

Comment: I started to use  Dask since I'm running large files (at least 15GB). and it helps from the beginning to avoid OOM.
I never imagine to use df.apply(list, axis=1). I was just thinking in iteration or to_list(). I'll try this :) 
thanks!.

Comment: It makes sense. I personally prefer `dask` but you could have a look at `vaex` too.

Comment: Then is 15 GB as csv or parquet? I found working with parquet ways more efficient. As the file is smaller, load faster and keep the dtypes you assign.

Comment: It's a CSV of round 15GB.